# Join inserted record with latest record target table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i'm setting up a trigger that, in case of a new record being added to my source table, inserts a record into my target table with information based on the data in the first inserted record.

Since the new data in the target table are basically calculated fields based on the original latest record in the target table and the inserted record in the source table, i basically need a way to join the last record of my target table and my INSERTED table.

i've tried selecting the top row of my target table and join this with my INSERTED table, but so far it has not worked

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.NewData  ON dbo.t_stats_lijn1 AFTER INSERT  AS     
IF Exists(select top 1 Categorie from INSERTED where Categorie = 'geen stop' order by p_timestamp desc) 
begin
declare @joincause int = 0
insert into dbo.T_VALUE_LIJN1 ([Event ID]
      ,[p_timestamp]
      ,[Model]
      ,[Modelnaam]
      ,[running_time]
      )
      select
      i.event_id,
      i.p_timestamp
      i.model
      t.running_time + i.delta
      from inserted i left join (select top 1 * from t_value_lijn1 order by p_timestamp) t on @joincause = 0

      end
      go
```

Comment: What does *"not worked"* mean? In your SQL above, your `LEFT JOIN` is missing an `ON` clause; is that the problem?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add my on clause, added now.

Comment: That `ON` looks odd. It looks like it has nothing to do with the main query. You would be better off using `APPLY` here it seems.

Comment: You haven't, however, answered what *"not worked"* means, so we still can't help you as we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, turned out that joining the INSERTED table with the (select * from t_value_lijn1 order by p_timestamp desc) was the way to go. i just had some other stuff that needed optimising, i don't know if it's the cleanest way to do it but so far, it does the job.